# Change value in one column if a value in another is in a list [R]

Tags: r, dplyr

Hello I have a df such as :

```
COL1 COL2
A 1
B 2
C 3
D 4
E 5
F 6

List<-c("A","C")
```

and if a `COL1` value is in `List`, then add "OK" into the `COL2`

I should then get:

```
COL1 COL2
A OK
B 2
C OK
D 4
E 5
F 6
```

Here are the data

```
structure(list(COL1 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), COL2 = 1:6), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `%in%` + `replace` like below

```
transform(
  df,
  COL2 = replace(COL2, COL1 %in% List, "OK")
)
```

which gives

```
  COL1 COL2
1    A   OK
2    B    2
3    C   OK
4    D    4
5    E    5
6    F    6
```

---

A `dplyr` option

```
> df %>%
+   mutate_at("COL2", ~ replace(., COL1 %in% List, "OK"))
  COL1 COL2
1    A   OK
2    B    2
3    C   OK
4    D    4
5    E    5
6    F    6
```

Comment: Is it normal I get the message ```incorrect factor level, NAs generated```with another daframe ?

Comment: It does work better with the dplyr solution, thanks

Comment: @Grendel I have no idea why `incorrect factor level, NAs generated` occurs ....